# What Came First, the Torah or the Jew?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

This is apparently an age old debate, and *really is a question about what is primary*; more important. The midrash (Tanna D'Bei Eliyahu Rabbah, ch. 14. See also Bereshit Rabbah 1:4) asks this question:

"Torah and the Jewish people both preceded creation. But which of the two came first?"

It then concludes that the Jewish people came first as the Torah is addressed to them. This is an argument from logic, and we have no "shema mina", so apparently the Midrash isn't definitive, which is another way of saying "we will debate this until the end".

Clearly this is true. Maybe the first recorded debate on this issue is between Esther and Mordechai. Esther asks Mordechai to call a fast to nullify the decree of destruction that was taking place through Haman. Mordechai was arguing that this can't be done because it would be on the first night of Pesach and therefore we wouldn't be able to hold a Seder. Esther won the argument by saying "if there are no Jewish people, then who will keep future sedarim?" (Esther Rabbah 8:7). Hashem didn't say "if I can't have sedarim, I don't want Jews", but rather "if I can't have Jews, then I don't want sedarim". But it's not water tight, as this might imply that the argument to save the Jews is contingent on the fact that there might be future sedarim! Also, it's not clear how we should take this down to the individual level (as it is a story of the *entire Jewish people*, and there are plenty of ways to argue that if a Jew doesn't keep Mitzvot, the Torah has some not nice things to say about him...)

I would like to ask, **have we reached any consensus on this yet**? It seems on the surface that this might, for example, be at the heart of the old *chassidic*/*misnagdic* battles, with one side placing the Jew as primary, and halacha as secondary, and visa versa. It might be at the heart of different kiruv movements, with one side trying to "bring Jews to mitzvot" and one side trying to "bring mitzvot to Jews". It seems important in deciding how we should treat Jews who do not keep halacha and mitzvot, either with love or scorn or something in between.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe would take a side on this. [He would teach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKjhp8_A7TY) that the Talmud explains that in the first of the Ten Commandments, "I am Hashem your God...," the word "I -- Anochi" forms an acronym: "I inscribed My soul and gave it over." This means that Hashem Himself invested His very essence into the words of  His Torah. Nevertheless, the Jewish people are higher in His mind (His inner will), even than Torah. Are there any other gedolim who make arguments in this vein either way?

**So who holds what, and more importantly, what are the nafka minas (the practical differences) of this point?**

Note: clearly both are vitally important (which is why we are debating it until this day) so I don't want to see this used as an opportunity to argue against the importance of either.